# Grouping datetime fields if speed data more than 60 km/h in a row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to group date_created and device_id column if the speed data more than 60 km/h,

I keep trying for a weeks still don't find any solution.

Here my data:

```
id    device_id        date_created              speed
1        34       2016-11-24 05:00:00.000         30
2        35       2016-11-24 05:00:00.000         45
3        34       2016-11-24 05:00:45.000         75
4        35       2016-11-24 05:00:45.000         56
5        34       2016-11-24 05:01:30.000         80
6        35       2016-11-24 05:01:30.000         63
7        34       2016-11-24 05:02:15.000         91
8        35       2016-11-24 05:02:15.000         65
9        34       2016-11-24 05:03:00.000         60
10       35       2016-11-24 05:03:00.000         50
11       34       2016-11-24 05:03:45.000         20
12       35       2016-11-24 05:03:45.000         50
13       34       2016-11-24 05:04:30.000         61
14       35       2016-11-24 05:04:30.000         65
15       34       2016-11-24 05:05:15.000         79
16       35       2016-11-24 05:05:15.000         70
```

After grouping (Desire Result):

```
arrayId    array_DevId                      arrayDateC                                                  arraySpeed
[3,5,7]    [34,34,34]   [2016-11-24 05:00:45.000, 2016-11-24 05:00:45.000, 2016-11-24 05:02:15.000]     [75,80,91]
[13,15]    [34,34]      [2016-11-24 05:04:30.000, 2016-11-24 05:05:15.000]                              [61,79]
[6,8]      [35,35]      [2016-11-24 05:01:30.000, 2016-11-24 05:02:15.000]                              [63,65]
[14,16]    [35,35]      [2016-11-24 05:04:30.000, 2016-11-24 05:05:15.000]                              [65,70]
```

What i already get is i can group by speed and device id, but still didn't have the clue to group by datetime in a row. what i get in my arrayDateC is like [2016-11-24 05:00:45.000, 2016-11-24 06:00:45.000, 2016-11-24 05:20:15.000]

Here my code:

```
SELECT array_agg(id) AS arrayid,
       array_agg(device_id) AS arraydevid, 
       array_agg(date_created) AS arraydatec, 
       array_agg(speed) AS arrayspeed
FROM speed_event
WHERE speed > 60 
  AND date_created >= '2016-11-24' AND date_created <=  '2016-11-25'
GROUP BY speed > 60, date_created, device_id
ORDER BY date_created
```

Comment: That is your current result after grouping, or your desire result?

Comment: Sorry, current result after grouping is my desire result.

Comment: @AfiqAbdullah What's your current result?

Comment: can you explain the group logic? `[3,5,7]` doesnt have spd 60 in a row.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran my current result is i got mixed up datetime. for example in my desire result above. they group device 34 in one row and device 35 in one row.

Comment: Is better if you show it in a table code like your desire result. That way is easy to see what is wrong.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes it is. the result should catch speed more than 60km/h in row

Comment: But `[4]` is `56`, still dont understand the logic, what mean `in a row` for you?

Comment: On what basis you got `[3,5,7]` as one group?? Even 2nd row `[13,15]` is having same `device_id`   and `date_created` .

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza and Jibin Balachandran,
Here what i want, i'm sorry i couldn't explain better in english. Right now i want to know car speed acceleration in day. How many times the car exceed speed limit more than 60km/h. for example: car have accelerate more then 60km/h 5 times a day. So i need to pull the data the frequencies of speed limit breach. that's why it have two rows. [3,5,7] and [13,15] group by same car device id. That's mean the car have breach limit 2 times already. But my code only manage to group one rows perday. eg: [3,5,7,13,15]

Comment: ohh now I see it... I told you if you post current result we can see it  faster ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza glad you understand.. the stroke - hard to explain

Comment: @AfiqAbdullah  'So I need to pull the data the frequencies of speed limit breach', I didn't understand this point.

Comment: Ok, i lost again, why you have two groups for device `[34]` ? they are all in same date

Comment: @Jibin Balachandran let say.. car A  breach speed limit for today date. The device send sms 45 second a day. So car A drove more then 60km/h in the morning, evening and night. The speed in the morning 61,75,85 in sequence, in evening 80,85 in sequence. In night 65, 67,78 in sequence. So i have frequency of 3 rows breaching speed limit perday. That is what i meant by frequencies of speed limit breach

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza. That is frequencies of device [34]. So thats mean device [34] have two frequencies of breach speed limit.

Comment: Dont get it, even when read the explanation to Jibin All dates for 34 are `2016-11-24 05:xx:xx` where is the frequency?

Comment: @Afiq Abdullah,answer jibin's question then only move forward

Comment: I give up ...
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Afiq Abdullah Grouping is the act of associating a single row to a single unique value of the grouping variable. The desired result you wrote doesn't respond to any evident grouping rule to us. `GROUP BY device_id, date_created` produces a single row for each combination of the values assumed by `device_id` and `date_created`. The condition `speed > 60` must be put inside the `WHERE` condition. Also, following your description, the desired result is wrong as we expect that you are aggregating in a fency way ("day", "evening", "night"). Please, write the correct output or be more clear.